# Short integer solution lattice problem with q=2

Tags: lattice-crypto, sis

For large values of $q$, we know that there are worst-case lattice problems which reduce to the average-case [short integer solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_integer_solution_problem_) (SIS) problem. Does this means that for $q=2$, the SIS problem is NOT hard-on-average?

Comment: No, it just means we don't have such theoretical evidence for its hardness. The problem does still appear to be quite hard, though.

Comment: please define technical terms like SIS.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert: Thanks. Is there any constructions based on this version of SIS? If yes, would you please cite some papers which address this issue?

Comment: With such small moduli, you're better off looking into coding theory. SIS with $q = 2$ looks similar to finding a low-weight codeword in a random linear code.